# Installing arch, grub can't see any linux img

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I am installing arch linux on my laptop. I am doing it from arch linux Wiki install Guide. Everything is going fine until the bootloader config. I choose grub. I make `grub-install /dev/sda`

Then `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

The output of comand is: `generating grub configuration file ...
done`

There's no "found linux image". I did try efi and legacy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [install essential packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Install_essential_packages) step, was the kernel installation successful?

If it was, you should have a kernel file named like `/boot/vmlinuz-*` (the exact name will depend on which exact kernel package was chosen).

On installation of the kernel package, the `pacstrap` command should also have generated an initramfs file for you (something like `/boot/*.img`). If it is missing, and you used the `linux` kernel package, you could use `mkinitcpio -p linux` to try generating it again.

The kernel and the initramfs files are the things `grub-mkconfig` looks for when it searches for Linux images. The choice of EFI vs. legacy only affects how the parts of the bootloader will be laid out; the kernel and initramfs files should be in the same location either way.